# HTML email with linked images breaks in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, email-client

I have created a simple html email with images with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
<div style="width: 720px; margin: 0pt auto; overflow:hidden; font-size:0; line-height:0;">
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0401_3.jpg" height="176" border="0" width="720"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0402_3.jpg" height="50" border="0" width="478"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Antwerp-Jewels/176579572442840" target="_blank"><img style="display:inline; border:0;" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_likeButton1_3.jpg" height="50" border="0" width="165"></a><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0404_3.jpg" height="50" border="0" width="77"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0405_3.jpg" height="238" border="0" width="720"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0406_3.jpg" height="13" border="0" width="272"><a href="http://www.antwerpjewels.co.uk" target="_blank"><img style="display:inline; border:0;" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_siteLink1_3.jpg" height="13" border="0" width="176"></a><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0408_3.jpg" height="13" border="0" width="272"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0409_3.jpg" height="112" border="0" width="720"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0410_3.jpg" height="27" border="0" width="503"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Antwerp-Jewels/176579572442840" target="_blank"><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_likeButton2_3.jpg" height="27" border="0" width="52"></a><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0412_3.jpg" height="27" border="0" width="165"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0413_3.jpg" height="133" border="0" width="720"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0414_3.jpg" height="27" border="0" width="503"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Antwerp-Jewels/176579572442840" target="_blank"><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_likeButton3_3.jpg" height="27" border="0" width="52"></a><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0416_3.jpg" height="27" border="0" width="165"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0417_3.jpg" height="131" border="0" width="720"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0418_3.jpg" height="17" border="0" width="356"><a href="http://www.antwerpjewels.co.uk" target="_blank"><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_siteLink2_3.jpg" height="17" border="0" width="162"></a><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0420_3.jpg" height="17" border="0" width="202"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0421_3.jpg" height="36" border="0" width="720"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0422_3.jpg" height="48" border="0" width="282"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Antwerp-Jewels/176579572442840" target="_blank"><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_likeButton4_3.jpg" height="48" border="0" width="157"></a><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0424_3.jpg" height="48" border="0" width="281"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0425_3.jpg" height="55" border="0" width="720"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0426_3.jpg" height="15" border="0" width="256"><a href="http://www.antwerpjewels.co.uk" target="_blank"><img style="display:inline;" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_siteLink3_3.jpg" height="15" border="0" width="159"></a><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0428_3.jpg" height="15" border="0" width="305"></div>
<div><img style="display:inline" src="http://img.emailnewsletter-software.net/n869_0429_3.jpg" height="42" border="0" width="720"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is showing properly in all the email clients that I tested it in but Outlook! All the linked images show irregular whitespace around them like shown in the image below.

[image]

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the Div's that are causing the issue.  Outlook treats DIVs differently than a browser, usually giving them double line-spacing.  Try using a SPAN instead.

Comment: It was a DIV issue indeed. I used table instead and it worked fine. It seems that Outlook is still using an outdated rendering engine. I am a sharing a cool PDF I found on the internet which can help a lot while composing HTML emails. Hope it helps someone: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/downloads/documents-tools/campaign-monitor-guide-to-css-in-email-sept-2011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, because I don't have Outlook to run a test, but try setting no border on the link itself:

```
<a href="http://www.antwerpjewels.co.uk" target="_blank" style="border: none;">
```

Or failing that, try:

```
<a href="http://www.antwerpjewels.co.uk" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
```